# SQL - Joining/Referencing columns of multiple tables

Tags: java, join, reference, attributes, alias

Writing this in Oracle Live SQL and I'm a newbie. I need to reference multiple attributes of my TRUCK table to the condition of one value within my BASE table. Here are my tables I created and the tasks to be performed:

BASE and TRUCK tables

• Display truck number, buy date, and mileage of all trucks with Dallas as their base.

• Display truck number and buy date of all trucks with Dallas as their base and with mileage lower than 30,000 miles.

Been struggling and nothing is working. I keep getting "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" I've tinkered with JOIN and without... Thank you in advance. I'm sure if I can understand the first task I can understand the second.

```
create table BASE 
( BASENUM CHAR(3) NOT NULL, 
BASECITY VARCHAR2(20), 
BASESTATE CHAR(2), 
BASEPHON VARCHAR2(10), 
BASEMGR VARCHAR2(10), 
PRIMARY KEY(BASENUM) 
);
INSERT INTO BASE (BASENUM, BASECITY, BASESTATE, BASEPHON, BASEMGR)
VALUES (501, 'Dallas', 'TX', 893-9870, 'J. Jones');
INSERT INTO BASE (BASENUM, BASECITY, BASESTATE, BASEPHON, BASEMGR)
VALUES (502, 'New York', 'NY', 234-7689, 'K. Lee');

create table TRUCK  
( TNUM CHAR(4) NOT NULL,  
BASENUM CHAR(3),  
TYPENUM CHAR(1),  
TMILES NUMBER(7,1),  
TBOUGHT DATE,  
TSERIAL VARCHAR2(20),  
PRIMARY KEY(TNUM),  
FOREIGN KEY (BASENUM)
REFERENCES BASE(BASENUM)
);
INSERT INTO TRUCK (TNUM, BASENUM, TYPENUM, TMILES, TBOUGHT, TSERIAL)
VALUES (1001, 501, 1, 5900.2, to_date('1990-11-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'aa-125');
INSERT INTO TRUCK (TNUM, BASENUM, TYPENUM, TMILES, TBOUGHT, TSERIAL)
VALUES (1002, 502, 2, 64523.9, to_date('1990-11-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'ac-213');
INSERT INTO TRUCK (TNUM, BASENUM, TYPENUM, TMILES, TBOUGHT, TSERIAL)
VALUES (1003, 501, 2, 32116.0, to_date('1991-09-29', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'ac-215');
INSERT INTO TRUCK (TNUM, BASENUM, TYPENUM, TMILES, TBOUGHT, TSERIAL)
VALUES (1004, NULL, 2, 3256.9, to_date('1992-01-14', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'ac-315');
```

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: What is your question? When you get a result that you don't expect/understand, stop trying to find your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first unexpected/misunderstood subexpression & its input & output & learn what misconception, typo, wrong reasoning, etc led to it. Then compose a new overall query. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: An error message is almost certainly a faq. (And so is a beginner's query or its parts.) Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Show what parts you can do, don't ask us to rewrite your textbook with with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Thanks but another person understood my issue and answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `Inner Join` or `Left Outer Join` will help you to achieve the objectives.

For the first question,

> Display truck number, buy date, and mileage of all trucks with Dallas as their base.

```
SELECT tnum, tbought, tmiles FROM Truck T LEFT OUTER JOIN Base B ON T.basenum = B.basenum WHERE B.basecity='Dallas'
```

For the second question,

> Display truck number and buy date of all trucks with Dallas as their base and with mileage lower than 30,000 miles.

```
SELECT tnum, tbought, tmiles FROM Truck T LEFT OUTER JOIN Base B ON T.basenum = B.basenum WHERE B.basecity='Dallas' AND T.tmiles < 30000
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! I think I'm getting the hang of JOINs. I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Great that I was able to help you.  An upvote would be a nice appreciation :)

Comment: Venkat_The_Mufasa @StevieJ321 doesn't have the reputation to upvote, but they can accept. Google with 'stackexchange' for more info.

Comment: Yes, I accepted the functional and helpful answer. Thanks again!